# No Space Left on Device android emulator; even after wiping data

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I wiped an android emulator and rebuilt it with about 100mb sd and 200mb local storage.

I still get the

```
NAND: could not write file C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP7343.tmp, No space left on device
```

error even after wiping user data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete some files from C:/ drive. Seems it full.

Comment: Silly mistake; I had thought I had installed it through my d: drive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is not the filesystem where you try to write the emulator temp file to that is out of space?

Answer (score 0):

Delete tmp files from this location

**C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator**

AppData is a hidden folder

If the emulator is open it will ask to skip the file,skip it and delete rest !